# javascript getElementById function not working

Tags: javascript, string, variables, dom, getelementbyid

I tried the following: it is working fine

```
function saveTitle(index,id){
   arrtitle[1] = document.getElementById("title_1").value;
   arrtitle[2] = document.getElementById("title_2").value;
   arrtitle[3] = document.getElementById("title_3").value;
}
```

but as I tried the following:

```
function saveTitle(index,id){
   for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
   arrtitle[i] = document.getElementById("title_"+i).value;
}
```

It gives me an error that : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Please suggest me something. Thanks...

Comment: And what is the value of `"title_"+i` when you get that error? Have you tried logging it?

Comment: What is `count` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the elements that contains "title_" string . See the bellow code.

```
function getTitles() {
  var arrtitle = [];
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*[id*='title_']");

  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var titleId = elements[i].id.replace("title_", "");
    arrtitle[titleId] = elements[i].value;
  }
  return arrtitle;
}
getTitles();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted, if that's your actual code, the only possibility seems to be that `count` is higher than the maximum element that exists (or there's a hole). For example, `count` might be 4, and there is no element with the id of `title_4`.

The javascript debugger would help you find this pretty easily.

I'd also suggest using braces around the body of your `for` loop, which would significantly help readability.